# How configure a RESTful controller in Spring 3 with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RESTful) controller using [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) 3.0. The controller is for a management API for a portal application. The operations I want to perform are:

- GET /api/portals to list all the portals
- POST /api/portals to create a new portal
- GET /api/portals/{id} to retrieve an existing portal
- PUT /api/portals/{id} to update an existing portal
- DELETE /api/portal/{id} to delete an existing portal

After annotating the controller as illustrated below I find the the operations to list all the portals or create a new portal do not get mapped.

So my questions are:

- Have I annotated the class correctly?
- Am I following the correct conventions for implementing a RESTful web service?
- Might there be something broken in Spring?

The code extract below shows how I have annotated my class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/portals")
public final class PortalAPIController
{
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PortalAPIController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPortals(final Model model)
    {
         PortalAPIController.LOGGER.debug("Portal API: listPortals()");
         .
         .
         return "portals";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createPortal(@RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String> portalData, final Model model)
    {
        PortalAPIController.LOGGER.debug("Portal API: createPortal()");
        .
        .
        return "portal";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPortal(@PathVariable("id") final String portalId, final Model model, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
    {
        PortalAPIController.LOGGER.debug("Portal API: getPortal()");
        .
        .
        return "portal";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updatePortal(@PathVariable("id") final String portalId,
        @RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String> portalData, final Model model, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
    {
        PortalAPIController.LOGGER.debug("Portal API: updatePortal()");
        .
        .
        return "portal";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deletePortal(@PathVariable("id") final String portalId, final Model model, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
    {
        PortalAPIController.LOGGER.debug("Portal API: deletePortal()");
        .
        .
        return "portal";
    }

    .
    .
}
```

During start-up I am seeing that Spring things it has registered the end-points:

```
2010-02-19 01:18:41,733 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/api/portals/] onto handler [com.btmatthews.mars.portal.web.controller.PortalAPIController@141717f]
2010-02-19 01:18:41,734 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/api/portals/{id}] onto handler [com.btmatthews.mars.portal.web.controller.PortalAPIController@141717f]
2010-02-19 01:18:41,734 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/api/portals/{id}.*] onto handler [com.btmatthews.mars.portal.web.controller.PortalAPIController@141717f]
2010-02-19 01:18:41,735 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/api/portals/{id}/] onto handler [com.btmatthews.mars.portal.web.controller.PortalAPIController@141717f]
2010-02-19 01:18:41,735 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/api/portals] onto handler [com.btmatthews.mars.portal.web.controller.PortalAPIController@141717f]
2010-02-19 01:18:41,735 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/api/portals.*] onto handler [com.btmatthews.mars.portal.web.controller.PortalAPIController@141717f]
```

But when I try to invoke my API using cURL

```
curl http://localhost:8080/com.btmatthews.minerva.portal/api/portals/
```

or

```
curl http://localhost:8080/com.btmatthews.minerva.portal/api/portals
```

I get the following errors:

```
2010-02-19 01:19:20,199 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/com.btmatthews.minerva.portal/api/portals] in DispatcherServlet with name 'portal'
2010-02-19 01:19:32,360 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/com.btmatthews.minerva.portal/api/portals/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'portal'
```

I get the same problem when I try to do a create:

```
curl -F ...... --request POST http://localhost:8080/com.btmatthtews.minerva/api/portals
```

But if try to operate on an existing resource (retrieve, update or delete) it works okay.

**Update:** The solution was provided in a comment by [@axtavt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103154/axtavt). I was using <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern> in my web.xml servlet mapping. It needed to be changed to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: You might want to remove the value="/" in the list, create methods. it might confuse the url resolver.

another thing I noticed is a problem with namespaces. the methods are mapped to "com.btmatthews.mars" and you are getting errors for "com.btmatthews.minerva"

Comment: Taking out the value="/" didn't make any difference but when I tested I saw that the same URL mappings got registered so I'll remove it anyway. The the package name for the portal components is com.btmatthews.mars... but the application built on top of it is packaged in com.btmatthews.minerva.... Its confusing but not an issue.

Comment: The only possibility I can see is a wrong DispatcherServlet's `<url-pattern>`. For this configuration it should be `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`.

Comment: @axtavt - You were spot on. It turned out to be a incorrect <url-pattern/>. My fault for copying & pasting without reading the documentation first!

Comment: It would be good if axtavt could re-post the comment as an answer and then you can pick it as the correct one.

Comment: @stevendick that's what I'm hoping @axtavt will do

Comment: Well, you can always post the answer as CW, if @axtavt won't do that himself, and accept it.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and unit test your Spring MVC controllers using the excellent spring-test-mvc library (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc), which is in spring-test since Spring 3.2.

Comment: I am now using Spring MVC Test.

Answer (score 4):

Double check the `url-pattern` in your `web.xml` and compare it to your curl argument.

[Here is an example](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/16) I wrote which walks you through the whole Spring MVC process.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you post in your curl excerpt

```
http://localhost:8080/portal/api/portals
```

does not match the URL in the Spring warning

```
/com.btmatthews.minerva.portal/api/portals
```

Without knowing how your webapp is set up, what context path it's at, what the Spring context looks like, etc., it's pretty hard to diagnose but this sounds like a big clue to me.

Comment: The correct context root was /com.btmatthews.minerva.portal rather portal. I updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You Have done few Mistakes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String listPortals(final Model model)
{
}
```

Over here the method must accept some parameter Model, but that's not passed.
you must write that inside method. or if u want to pass that, u must sent it as path variable or as a request Param.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String getPortal(@PathVariable("id")
```

here the correct syntax is  `@PathVariable(value="id")`

And if this doesn't work 
then try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SOMETHING", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: It is generally not helpful to answer questions this old, especially when the question has been updated with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 3, the Rest Controller is no more than a regular controller (@Component) and the only difference is that a Rest controller returns JSON/XML instead of "Views". So I think you are doing ok with respect to annotations. However, two missing things I can't see:
1- Every method needs to have a "produce" value (for content negotiation):
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

2- You need an ObjectMapper of some type (ex: Marshaller and Unmarshaller) to be able to map objects to JSON/XML and vice-versa. Those two should be in your servlet config, instead of configuring a view resolver.
And that should be it.